# Nodeshift - unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: angular, npm, deployment, openshift

I am middle of a deployment Angular application by nodeshift, but I am struggling with the following error **unable to verify the first certificate** that appears when I run this regular command:
`nodeshift --strictSSL=false --dockerImage=bucharestgold/centos7-s2i-web-app --imageTag=10.x --build.env OUTPUT_DIR=dist/angular-web-app`. Basically, I have a configured proxy by my corporate, so npm works fine, but I don't know if there is missing something during the usage of nodeshift.

Answer (score 0):

"bucharestgold/centos7-s2i-web-app" has been deprecated, you should use "nodeshift/centos7-s2i-web-app".

Also recent nodeshift releases by default points to [ubi8 images](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/search?q=ubi8%20nodejs) not nodeshift/centos7-s2i-nodejs anymore.

You can find examples of nodeshift usage here: https://github.com/nodeshift-starters